# Отображение элементов по оси z

Tags: css

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы элемент (изображение в формате png), поднятый по оси z вверх и перекрывающий полностью другое изображение, не мешал псевдоклассу :hover при наведении на нижнее изображение?

Чтобы визуально по оси z изображение было видимо, но не мешало работе с другими компонентами, которые закрывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно помочь. Но проверь поддержку браузерами:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Как обычно: IE не поддерживает :) Остальные вроде должны: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: @cyadvert, 1. я не знаю, нужны ли автору IE10-. 2. Есть подозрение, что если использовать svg, то поддерживаться будет в IE9+, только я не проверял этого.

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш подход помог.)

Comment: А не подскажите где можно найти русско язычную спецификацию по этому свойству?

Comment: @ИванСмирнов, тогда надо поставить плюсик и принять ответ ;)

Comment: Я пытаюсь, вот сейчас пишет что еще 13 секунд, сейчас все приму.)
Может из за того что не так давно на сайте сразу не могу принимать.)

Comment: @ИванСмирнов, на русском не знаю. Но я ни разу не пользовался значениями кроме all и none. А с ними вроде и так всё ясно.

Comment: Как такового руководства по-русски я не нашел. Но вот тут неплохо с примерами, плюс ссылка на остальные значения свойства: http://paulradzkov.com/2012/pointer-events/

Comment: @cyadvert, по-английски есть MDN: [для css](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) и [для svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) - переводов пока нет.